# error: cannot find symbol on React Native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I want to build a VPN app with React Native and cloned a repository from this [GitHub](https://github.com/sijav/react-native-ip-sec-vpn).
When I run the project with `yarn android`, it throws me error like this:

```
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
/Users/rurjaf/React-Native/FourthVPN/node_modules/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/android/src/main/java/org/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService.java:374: error: cannot find symbol
                .setSmallIcon(androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp)
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable abc_ic_star_black_48dp
  location: class drawable
/Users/rurjaf/React-Native/FourthVPN/node_modules/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/android/src/main/java/org/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService.java:382: error: cannot find symbol
            builder.setSmallIcon(androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp);
                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable abc_ic_star_black_48dp
  location: class drawable
/Users/rurjaf/React-Native/FourthVPN/node_modules/react-native-ip-sec-vpn/android/src/main/java/org/strongswan/android/logic/CharonVpnService.java:409: error: cannot find symbol
                    builder.setSmallIcon(androidx.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp);
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   variable abc_ic_star_black_48dp
  location: class drawable
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I deleted the node_modules and installed it again with `yarn add` but I am still facing the same issue. Also I run `./gradlew clean`, but still facing the same issue.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you please share gradel file

Comment: the build.gradle file from /MyProject/android or from /MyProject/android/app ? @MahammadMomin